# Magic Square Program Outputs Incorrect Sum Values for Rows, Columns, Diagonals

Tags: java, magic-square

I coded a Magic Square program with a driver and a class. The only problem I'm having is adding up the rows, columns, and diagonals. I made a int constant called "col" for column, that counts up 1 each time an entire row is summed. Therefore, the multi-dimensional array would first sum [0,0],[0,1],[0,2] to whatever size the square is, and then col would be incremented, changing to [1,0],[1,1],[1,2] etc. However, after my adding method computes one row, goes to print, and comes back for the next row, col is set back to 0. Is there a way I can prevent it from resetting and keep its incrementation? I think that's the final step. Note: I only put the col on the row and column sum methods so far, I just want to get it to work for those first.

Note: Please make sure you name the text file correctly when transferring the text given here

Thank you all in advance.

```
// ****************************************************************
// MagicSquare.java
//
// Text below is to be filled by student. 
//
// ****************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MagicSquare 
{ 
    int[][] square;
    public MagicSquare(int size)
    {
      square = new int[size][size];      
    }
    int col = 0;
//--------------------------------------
//return the sum of the values in the given row
//--------------------------------------

    private int sumMagicRow(int size,int col)
    {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i=0;i<(size);i++)
      {
         sum += square[col][i];
      }
      col++;
      return sum;
    }
//--------------------------------------
//return the sum of the values in the given column
//--------------------------------------

    private int sumMagicCol(int size, int col)
    {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
         sum += square[col][i];
      }
      col++;
      return sum;
    }
//--------------------------------------
//return the sum of the values in the main diagonal
//--------------------------------------

    private int sumMagicDiagMain(int size)
    {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
         sum += square[i][i];
      }
      return sum;
    }
//--------------------------------------
//return the sum of the values in the other ("reverse") diagonal
//--------------------------------------

    private int sumMagicDiagRev(int size)
    {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
         sum += square[i][(size-1)-i];
      }
      return sum;
    }

//--------------------------------------
//return true if the square is magic (all rows, cols, and diags
// have same sum), false otherwise
//-------------------------------------- 
    public boolean isMagicSquare(int size)
    {
       boolean answer =false;
       if(sumMagicCol(size,col)==sumMagicRow(size,col) && sumMagicRow(size,col)==sumMagicDiagMain(size) && sumMagicDiagMain(size)==sumMagicDiagRev(size))
       {
         answer=true;
       }
       return answer;
    }
//--------------------------------------
//compute and display sums of square including row, column, main diagonal, and other diagonal
//--------------------------------------
    public void printMagicSquareSums(int size)
    {
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Sum of row " + i + " is: " + sumMagicRow(size,col));
      }
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Sum of column " + i + " is: " + sumMagicCol(size,col));
      }
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Sum of row " + i + " is: " + sumMagicDiagMain(size));
      }
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Sum of row " + i + " is: " + sumMagicDiagRev(size));
      }
    }

//--------------------------------------
//read info into the square from the input stream associated with
//the Scanner parameter
//--------------------------------------
    public void readSquare(Scanner scan)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++)
           for (int col = 0; col < square.length; col++)
              square[row][col] = scan.nextInt();
    }
//--------------------------------------
//print the contents of the square, neatly formatted
//--------------------------------------
    public void printSquare(int size)
    {
      int column=0;
      for(int x=0;x<size;x++)
      {
         for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
         {
            System.out.printf("%3d ",square[x][i]);
         }
         System.out.println("");
      }

    }          
}
```

Driver program:

```
// ****************************************************************
// MagicSquareTest.java
//
// Text below is to be filled by student. 
//
// ****************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class MagicSquareTest
{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
     {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("magicText.txt"));


      // make sure that the file magicData is in the current directory
      int count = 1; //count which square we're on
      int size = scan.nextInt(); //size of next square
      int mem = size;

      //Expecting -1 at bottom of input file
      while (size != -1)
      {

         //create a new Square of the given size 
         MagicSquare s = new MagicSquare(size);
         size=mem;

         //call its read method to read the values of the square
         System.out.println("\n***** Square " + count + " *****");
         s.readSquare(scan);

         //print the square
         s.printSquare(size);

         //print the square id
         //System.out.println(count);

         //print the sums
         s.printMagicSquareSums(size);

         //determine and print whether it is a magic square
         System.out.println(s.isMagicSquare(size));
         //get size of next square
         size = scan.nextInt();
         count++;
     }
   }
}
```

Text File (that reads into array)

```
3
8  1  6
3  5  7
4  9  2
7
30  39  48   1  10  19  28
38  47   7   9  18  27  29
46   6   8  17  26  35  37
5   14  16  25  34  36  45  
13  15  24  33  42  44   4
21  23  32  41  43   3  12
22  31  40  49   2  11  20 
4
48   9   6   39
27  18  21   36
15  30  33   24
12  45  42    3
3
6  2  7
1  5  3
2  9  4
4
3  16   2  13
6   9   7  12
10  5  11   8
15  4  14   1
5
17  24  15   8   1
23   5  16  14   7
 4   6  22  13  20
10  12   3  21  19
11  18   9   2  25
7
30  39  48   1  10  28  19
38  47   7   9  18  29  27
46   6   8  17  26  37  35
5   14  16  25  34  45  36  
13  15  24  33  42   4  44
21  23  32  41  43  12   3
22  31  40  49   2  20  11 
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I find your code very weird and you still have a lot to fix in it in my opinion. But for your specific question:

```
private int sumMagicRow(int size,int col)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<(size);i++)
  {
     sum += square[col][i];
  }
  col++;
  return sum;
}
```

Here you give col to the method and it is different then the field (it's not constant) col in the class. In col++ you increment that sumMagicRow(int size,int **col**). If you want to increment the class instance value you should use **this.col** which says use the col which is not defined in that particular scope (method) but on class level.

Unfortunately reading through your code I think it will not solve the problem because sooner or later you will want col to go back to 0 ;) otherwise if you keep adding to it you will leave the bounds of the array. For example if you have square with size 3 and you go read col1, col2, col3 when you go to rows col will be already 3 and you will try to read row 4. It would be better to rethink your algorithm. There are many things to improve.

For example if you have a loop for 1 to N (size of square) isn't one loop enough to check all rows/column/diagonals with some mathematics? I believe it should be ;)

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I know I have much to improve. My teacher gave us a shell that we had to use, so it isn't very efficient.